# LWC: How to display svg icons

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, svg-icon

I'm trying to render a button with an icon just next to the text, unfortunately, the icon doesn't show even if it uses the space next to the text.

```
<template>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assests/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#download"></use>
        </svg>Button Neutral
    </button>
</template>
```

I tried also using _slds instead of assets in the path.

Anyone can help me with this, please?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing  custom HTML, you an use the [`lightning-button`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example) base component:

```
<lightning-button variant="base" 
    label="Button Neutral" 
    icon-name="utility:download" 
    class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

---

If you rather want to use your own HTML for some specific reason, use the button example's markup from the [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Left-Icon):

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
<svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#download"></use>
</svg>Button Neutral</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I need to use a custom svg for the button and also when I use the button from SLDS documentation the button and the text on it renders but not the icon and I don't understand why, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The **correct** approach is the one Raul describes. However, if for whatever reason you did not want to use the `lighting-button` component (or you wanted to display an SVG outside of a component), you can display an SVG with the following LWC code:

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:download" alternative-text="Download" 
    title="Download" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example).